# Python How to generate file name

Tags: python, ssh

I was wondering if the community can help me out I'm a newbie to programming. I trying to ssh to a list of devices contain on "list.txt" once it logs into the router I send the same command to each one and write the output to a file. However, on the code below it overrides the output of each device. I need to create a unique file for each output with the name of the IP address that is contains on the "list.txt" file. If anybody can help me out I would really appreciated.

```
import paramiko
import time
import os


def disable_paging(remote_conn):
    '''Disable paging on a Cisco router'''

    remote_conn.send("terminal length 0\n")
    time.sleep(1)

    # Clear the buffer on the screen
    output = remote_conn.recv(1000)

    return output

#Create variables
f = open('list.txt')
filepath = ('test/tas.txt')
username = 'test'
password = 'test'
#Create a for loop 
for i in f:
    remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()

    remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(
                       paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    remote_conn_pre.connect(i, username=username, password=password)

    remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()

    output = remote_conn.recv(1000)

    disable_paging(remote_conn)

    # Now let's try to send the router a command
    remote_conn.send("\n")
    remote_conn.send("show int des\n")

    # Wait for the command to complete
    time.sleep(2)

    output = remote_conn.recv(88880000)

    # print output
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(filepath)):
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filepath))
    with open(filepath, "w") as f:
        f.write(output)
        f.close()
```

Comment: do u just want a unique file name?

Comment: Ideal would be to create the file name with the IP address from my list.txt file. If not possible then yes because then I'll have per say 5 IPs 5 outputs. Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just have your 'filepath' variable defined in the for loop, and use the 'i' string to create it :

```
for i in f:
    filename = 'tas_%s.txt' % str(i)
    filepath = os.path.join('test', filename)

    # anything else remains unchanged
```

Hope it works (difficult without knowing the content of 'list.txt').

Comment: Thanks!!!! I'll try it out. Btw the content of the list.txt file just contains a list of IP addresses, one IP per line.